# SQL - Select statement in brackets

Tags: sql, sas

is there a solution for putting the select statement in brackets or something like this?

I need to perform this:

```
select t1.plz, t1.help, t1.me AS...
```

The Problem is, that my columns getting from a variable and my code perform this

```
select t1.plz, help, me
```

It works to the point i join it with an other table and the key gets mixed up. This works - **t2.key, car,**...
but
**t2.car,key** not, because i need to rename key as key2 and without the t2.key in front it doenst work...long story.
I need to get that t1./t2. in front of every column.

Is there a solution for this problem?

My Code(SAS)

```
create table work.test as
select t1.&string1 t2.&string2
```

I can´t put the t1. in front of every string, because i perform a loop, so this would end in a t1.plz, t1.t1.help, t1.t1.t1,me.

Comment: Show the loop.  You will need to post more of the SQL query.  If the query is generated from control data show some sample control data and how the macro retrieves it and builds the query source code.  The nature of the join may require doing a `coalesce`, or using aliases for the tables, or requiring the column names (or variables) in control data to be specific to an aliases.  The macro might also need to do some pre-processing, such as examining the column names and types of the tables being joined, in order to emit the desired query source code.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `TRANWRD()` function to replace all the ", " with ", t1." then use `SYMPUTX()` to create the macro variables.

The Code below will fix this for you by creating the macros with the correct prefix:

```
data _null_;
%let str1= "plz, help, me";
%let str2= "plz, help, me";
t1= cats('t1.',tranwrd(&str1,", ",", t1."));
t2= cats('t2.',tranwrd(&str2,", ",", t2."));
call symputx('string1',t1,'L');
call symputx('string2',t2,'L');
put _all_;
run;
```

Output: The two macros &string1 and &string2 will have the values below.

```
t1.plz, t1.help, t1.me 
t2.plz, t2.help, t2.me
```

Comment: Thxs momo1644! 
I´m new to SAS...will give it a try.

Comment: You are welcome. Always happy to help. please approve my answer if it solved the problem.